# Access entity identifier in a custom Hibernate BasicType

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is there a way to access the entity identifier from a custom Hibernate BasicType.

The idea would be to compute this basic type using the entity identifier but for this, I would need to access the identifier from both the basic type itself and also from the BasicJavaDescriptor.

See the following portion of code for a concrete example

```
public class MyType extends AbstractStandardBasicType<MyCustomType> {
    
    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, boolean[] settable, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException {
        // how to access the entity identifier of the entity holding that field? Needed to compute the data of the custom type.
    }
    // other methods
}

public class MyDescriptor extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<MyCustomType> {
    
    @Override
    public <X> MyCustomType wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        // how to access the entity identifier of the entity holding that field? Needed to compute the data of the custom type.
    }
    // other methods
}
```

Hibernate version: 5.6.15.Final

The documentation on custom types is quite light.

Any help is more than welcome on that topic.

Comment: No idea what you’re trying to say here. Why not post some code to illustrate what you’re actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Description updated with an example. Hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're extending `AbstractStandardBasicType` here. That's not an extension point.

It looks like you should implement `UserType` instead. One of the methods you would implement is:

```java
J nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, int position, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner)
```

And `owner` is the owning entity, which would contain the id.

#### UPDATE

Th above answer is incorrect. The `owner` parameter is always null in H6.

Have you considered using `@PrePersist` and `@PostLoad` callbacks?

Comment: UserType may help but it seems it should not be used anymore. See TypeContributions#contributeType. Our project will be migrated to Hibernate 6 in a couple of weeks... So, if I trust the documentation, I should go back to a BasicType through a StandardBasicTypeTemplate. In brief, the idea of using a custom type is to support automatic/transparent encryption/decryption of sensitive data. We currently use a listener for that but it's not working well for lazy loading. So, we wanted something more internal.

Comment: `UserType` is *not* deprecated. Nor is the method `TypeContributions.contributeType(UserType)`. [The deprecation message you're referring to says: `Use {@link #contributeType(BasicType)} instead.`] We have not deprecated `UserType` (at least not yet) because there are cases where it is still the best/simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Much more clear.  Wondering how to retrieve the entity identifier from the nullSafeSet method? Regarding the nullSafeGet, anything to share to ease retrieving the identifier?

Comment: Maybe this kind of code may be used but this seems so fragile... session.getPersistenceContext().reentrantSafeEntityEntries() and then take the first id in the array...

Comment: could you please confirm it's possible to retrieve the entity id from the nullSafeSet method either using the proposal made in a previous comment or using a another way? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Ah no, sorry, the owning entity is only available from `nullSafeGet()`, not from `nullSafeSet()`, sorry.

Comment: Sad news, we wanted to implement a generic Spring support for automatic field encryption/decryption using a salt deduced from the entity id. We currently use listeners and we had good results, except with lazy loading aspects. So, we wanted something more "internal" to allow controlling such kind of issues but it seems we are blocked now. As the id is generally known by the caller, it would have been nice to expose it... Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: to allow accessing the id from the nullSafeSet method, I may propose a change and drop a PR in Hibernate. The idea would be to have a default overloaded method on the Type interface. So that, Hibernate would internally call this new method calling itself the original method without the identifier. It would allow an override if the id is needed. Later, we may deprecate the method without the id. Change would be quite basic and retro compatible. Any blocking reasons to not progress in that direction?

Comment: You could propose it, sure. But I can't guarantee it would be accepted. (I'm personally not hostile to the idea, but it would need to be properly thought through.)

Comment: Jira issue has been created with the proposal https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16550

Comment: It seems the owner is not set anymore when calling nullSafeGet with Hibernate 6.1.7 (see UserTypeSqlTypeAdapter.ValueExtractorImpl#extract). This is quite blocking for our use case. Any way to make it work? The id is needed to allow computing our field value. By the way, any feedback to give on the created Jira ticket? Any help would be more than welcome to allow progressing that topic. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, OK, I missed that. (In fact it looks like it was a mistake that this parameter was not removed.) See my update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pre* callbacks are already used but does not allow using lazy loading aspects. In future releases, it would be great to provide an access to the entity identifier in both the nullSafeGet and the nullSafeSet methods. Otherwise, it can be hard to compute custom fields. Jira issue has been created but no move on that...